# Where is the method getDriver initialized in java.sql.DriverManager in JAVA?

Tags: java, sql, driver, javap

I was going through classes in sql package. And i happened to look through the methods in DriverManager.class by "javap DriverManager.class". It shows a method of Driver class- get Driver , if i am not wrong. (Do correct me and tell me the correct info if i am). Now i looked through Driver.class and couldn't find that method. Where is that stored ? Thanks in advance.Image attached !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a method `Driver getDriver` when running `javap DriverManager.class` this means that there is a `DriverManager` method `getDriver` that *returns* a `Driver`, not that there is a `getDriver` method in the `Driver` class.